# rkhunter scan results

Tags: rkhunter

Im new to Ubuntu and im looking for some help.
I've scanned my Ubuntu with rkhunter and I have some concerning results:

```
Warning: The following processes are using deleted files:
Process: /sbin/init PID: 1 File: /var/log/upstart/systemd-logind.log.1
Process: /usr/sbin/cups-browsed PID: 1168 File: /etc/passwd
Process: /sbin/init PID: 2170 File: /home/pwn20wn/.cache/upstart/indicator-bluetooth.log.1
Process: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/bamf/bamfdaemon PID: 2400 File: /home/pwn20wn/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root
Process: /usr/lib/firefox/firefox PID: 2703 File: /var/tmp/etilqs_F4ZmiXL3Bx5CrjT
Process: /usr/bin/unity-scope-loader PID: 2959 File: /home/pwn20wn/.cache/software-center/software-center-agent.db/record.DB
Warning: Process '/sbin/wpa_supplicant' (PID 1167) is listening on the network.
Warning: Process '/sbin/dhclient' (PID 1349) is listening on the network.
Warning: Suspicious file types found in /dev:
/dev/.udev/rules.d/root.rules: ASCII text
Warning: Hidden directory found: /etc/.java: directory 
Warning: Hidden directory found: /dev/.udev: directory 
Warning: Hidden file found: /dev/.initramfs: symbolic link to `/run/initramfs' 
Warning: Application 'openssl', version '1.0.1f', is out of date, and possibly a security risk.
```

I would like to know if these are false positives or real threats abd how to fix them.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

RKHunter is famous for it's false positives. ClamAV is better!

Those 3 hidden directories are not dangerous! I get exactly these notifications since 2010.

The /etc/.java is created by Oracle Java and also by OpenJDK for digital certificates.

The /dev/.udev is created by the udevd daemon.

The /dev/.initramfs symlink for /run/initramfs is where the initial ram filesystem is mounted during the system boot process.

You can remove them without problem, they will be recreated by the system when necessary.